# How to prove range of a linear transformation is the column space of the transformation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Ok the title of the question might be a bit incomplete but I didnt know how else to convey it in the given word limit.

My textbook has the following statement

> In the special case where *A* is an $m \times n$ matrix and $T_A : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is multiplication by A, and the **range of $T_A$ is the column space of A**....

I have an issue with the part highlighted in bold. From my understanding, the dimension of the column space of $A$ is $n$  (since there are n columns) and dimension of vector space which contains the range is m, then how can they be the same?

Edit: After posting it I realized that the dimension of A need not necessarily be $n$ and can be lower. But even that out of the way I am having trouble understand how these two things can be equal. I am pretty new to linear algebra as evident so I have really poor grasp of these concepts

Comment: Column vectors in $\mathbb R^m$ are images of basis vectors in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: The range is all vectors of the form $Ax$. Look at how this multiplication is defined, and you should see that $Ax$ is just a linear combination of the columns of $A$ (the coefficients are the components of $x$).

Comment: @blamocur isnt the transformation a single column vector? And while I understand that they are images of the basis, how does that mean the images is the column space of $A$? Are you saying that the column space of $A$ is an image of the basis vectors of $A$

Comment: @Aditya The transformation is not a single column vector for the same reason that the function $f(x) = x^2$ is not a single number

Comment: @Aditya  Since columns are images of basis vectors the column space is the image of basis vectors space, i.e., image space of $T_A$.

Comment: @DavidMitra So basically the linear combination is $(a_{11} + a_{21}+...a_{m1})x_1 + ... (a_{1n} + a_{2n}....a_{mn})x_n$?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: @blamocur ok i am confused now, what is the linear transformation applied to make the columns images of the basis vectors? And wouldn't we need the transformations to be the same for the images to be equated?

Comment: @blamocur i understood it using the linear combination explanation given below but I still dont get the the image of basis thing you are saying and I would like to understand that

Comment: @Aditya matrix times vector (if defined) is the linear combination of the columns of the matrix where the coefficients of the combination are respective components of the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_{m×n}$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$

Then, $C(A) =span\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$

where $v_1, v_2,..., v_n\in\mathbb{R}^m$ columns of $A$.

Hence, $C(A) $ subspace of $\mathbb{R^m}$.

Associated linear map $ T_A : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ defined by $$T_A(x) =Ax$$

$R(T_A) =\{Ax: x\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$

$Ax= x_1v_1 +x_2v_2+... +x_nv_n$

where $x=(x_1, x_2,..., x_n) \in \mathbb{R^n}$

Hence, $R(T_A) =span\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$